# Qualtrics - use Hotspots to be directly forwarded to next page?

Tags: qualtrics, hotspot

maybe someone can help.

In an online-survey we want to use a graphic that looks and functions similar to Tinder. The respondents should be able to click on a heart or cross (in our case not swipe) under an image and directly see the next tinder-like image.
To do so we marked the heart and cross regions as hot spots.
The images one respondent will see are all in one block.
How can we manage

1. that it's only possible to mark one hot spot at a time? Currently you can activate both...
2. that the respondents immediately see the next image, as soon as they click on one of the hot spots? Currently you have to activate a hot spot and the click the "next question" button. And
3. that we can count for each respondent how often he/she clicked the heart or the cross?

Cheers, 
Anders

Comment: What is your question

Answer (score 2):

On your Hotspot questions:

Set Validation Type to:

- Answers Range
- At Least: 1
- No More Than: 1

Add this JavaScript:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        $('NextButton').click();
    };
});
```

The region they clicked for each question (heart or cross) will be in your response data.